# iperf3 download and upload test simultaniously giving abnormal results

Tags: networking, linux-networking, performance, wifi, iperf

I have a server (Lenovo using Ubuntu) and 2 clients (both Mac). The server is connected with a Wi-Fi router over Eth interface. The two clients are connected with Wi-Fi router over WLAN interface. All are connected and can communicate.

Now, I am using iperf3 (TCP) to test download and upload throughput (Mbps) of the clients. To do so, the server runs iperf3 on two terminals

Terminal 1 :

```
iperf3 -s -p 5001
```

Terminal 2 :

```
iperf3 -s -p 5002
```

On the other hand, Client 1 (downloading) runs

```
iperf3 -c 192.168.1.10 -p 5001 -R
```

And Client 2 (Uploading) runs

```
iperf3 -c 192.168.1.10 -p 5002
```

Both the client command executed at the same time. It is observed that client 2 (uploading) does not get fair share of the bandwidth, rather the upload rate goes down to 0 Mbps at times. While client 1 (downloading) has data rate > 70 Mbps.

Instead of uplpoad-download, I have also tested the scenario where both the clients are downloading simultaniously. This test works perfectly fine (both clients get fare share of the bandwidth (each 30 to 35 Mbps).

I do not have any traffic control rule / QoS rule in any of my router/machines.

Question: What is causing this unfairness of bandwidth sharing in TCP?

Comment: Your testing over wifi right? Same results when using a cable

Comment: Networkengineering.stackexchange.com might be better for this

Comment: @Turdie Yes, testing over wifi. Did not test over Eth. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was testing over wireless network or Wi-Fi (which is half-duplex). Two devices cannot transmit/receive simultaneously on the same frequency/channel. Which is the reason for unequal sharing of BW

Comment: remind to accept your own answer please